# Determining if a polynomial of a form is a subspace of all 3rd degree polynomails

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am suppose to determine if all polynomials of the form  $a_0 + a_1x +a_2x^2+a_3x^3$, where $a_0 = 0$ is a subspace of all 3rd degree polynomials.

I'm pretty sure I know the answer, but I'm just looking for verification of my understanding.

1. I first check to see if the zero vector belongs to the polynomial form given, indeed it does.
2. Whenever p(x) and q(x) belongs to the given polynomial form, then the addition of them must as well.

   - This is where it fails I believe, for instance if you had p(x) where the 3rd degree variable is $5x^3$ and q(x) is $-5x^3$, then in the total summation (whatever the other variables are), the total result would be of some form $0+ a_1x +a_2x^2+0$. Which can't be a subspace of $a_0 + a_1x +a_2x^2+a_3x^3$.

Is this the correct approach or am I misunderstanding anything?

Edit: Seeing as it is actually a subspace, anything with a degree equal to or less than 3 would be a subspace?

Comment: Rather than just checking if the "zero vector" belongs to the subset, you should check whether the subset is (a) nonempty and (b) closed under scalar multiplication (as well as (c) closed under vector addition).  These two facts imply the zero vector is an element (since you can take any vector in the subset and get the zero scalar multiple of it).

Comment: @hardmath By checking to see if it contains the zero vector, isn't that checking to see if its nonempty?

Comment: It does show the subset is nonempty (and it's a good check), but it doesn't prove the subset is closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: @hardmath I don't think pudge is asking if it's a vector space. This can be assumed if it's been proven that the set of all polynomials is a vector space. All he needs to do then is prove that a subset forms it's own subspace.

Comment: @Sentinel135:  In order to show a subset of a known vector space is a *subspace* you need (a) the subset is nonempty, (b) the subset is closed under scalar multiplication, and (c) the subset is closed under vector addition.  Two out of three is not enough, and the OP only articulated two requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The condition (from the way you've worded it) is just $a_0 = 0$ so even if $a_3 = 0$, you still belong in the subspace. So, I believe this is a subspace. A basis for this subspace is given by $\{x, x^2, x^3\}$. Now if the condition also included that $a_3 \not= 0$ then you are right, this is not a subspace.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. It would be a subspace after all. I was going over my notes, I believe I had some misunderstandings, but I believe I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if $\sum_{i=0}^3 a_1(x)^i$ such that $a_0=0$ is a subspace of all $3^{rd}$ degree polynomials or only $3^{rd}$ degree polynomials?

Either way it's no.

For the former stipulation. "if all the polynomials of the form $\sum_{i=0}^3 a_1(x)^i$ such that $a_0=0$ is a subspace of all $3^{rd}$ degree polynomials."

There exists a polynomial $p$ such that $p(x)= x^3+3x^2+3x+1$, $p$ would be defined as a polynomial of $3^{rd}$ degree. However as $a_0=1$, it doesn't live in the subspace.

---

For the latter stipulation "if all the polynomials of the form $\sum_{i=0}^3 a_1(x)^i$ such that $a_0=0$ is a subspace of only $3^{rd}$ degree polynomials."

In this situation you have the issue that if $a= x^3+x$ and $b=-x^3+x$ then $a+b=2x$ which lives in the subspace but isn't a $3^{rd}$ degree.

---

If we remove the stipulation that $a_0=0$ then yes this is still a subspace and it will have all of the polynomials of $3^{rd}$ degree contained within. However, it won't be a subspace with only $3^{rd}$ degree polynomials. Furthermore, any set of only $3^{rd}$ degree polynomials isn't a subspace, this is due to not having $0$ contained within.